Data extension Lock function
Is there a way to lock a DE so no one can clear it?
The DE then can only be un locked once send has gone out

You can't put this policy on a specific data extension. The only setting you can apply on a DE is to prevent users from change the attributes, as well as deleting it altogether:

If you want to prevent your users from clearing data, you will need to create and apply a custom role, like this one:

Remember, you will not need to set all the permissions - just deny clearing data and potentially managing data (to avoid specific records from being removed). When this role is applied to a user, the explicit Deny will overrule any Allow or empty setting for that particular permission. I know this will apply to all data extensions, but there are no other methods of achieving what you want.
